# Authenticate to Youtube REST with known credentials

Tags: authentication, youtube, youtube-api

I'm developing a web platform where different users can upload videos to my youtube channel.

So what I thought was the following flow:

On the server I auth to the Youtube REST API with my known credentials and then upload the video previously uploaded from the user to my server.

But it seems that I can not authenticate myself this way. In the docs there is always OAuth2 and that the user has to grant access to his account. But I just want to grant access to my account. The user who uploads this video has nothing to do with this process and also should not need an youtube account.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hello! I have the exact same requirement. I don't want to have the user log to YouTube to upload videos through my iOS app. I found this: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

The question is, does it work with YouTube?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

There is a deprecated feature which still exists: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_clientlogin#Authentication